# What are the odds to hit a straight with king queen pocket

Tags: texas-hold-em, odds

The river is 9, jack, Ace. What are the odds that I would've hit the 10 I needed?

Comment: This is assuming a full table.

Comment: I am assumin you meant the flop "The river is 9, jack, Ace"

Comment: Yes, the flop. I am dumb.